# Google Adwords Universal App Campaign Doesn't Work

Tags: google-ads, android

I am using Google Adwords Universal App Campaign to push my app install. However, after sometime I found out everything remains zero. There is no install and no impression at all.

How to get Google Adwords Universal App Campaign works?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. They seem to advertise everywhere but on google play. Although I'd bid a dollar, I'd get charges for like .26 cents because someone accidentally clicked it on you tube trying to get rid of the ad, even though it's supposed to be "If Downloaded". If google play removed the garbage apps that don't work right or no longer have support the whole thing would be better.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same issue. I called AdWords support and was informed by the representative that this is a result of a bid strategy that is too low.

He shared that the minimum is $1.00 (yet I find that hard to believe)

Answer (score 2):

Based upon my conversations with two Google ad reps (who didn't even know the Universal App Campaign ad units existed), I don't have much confidence that those folks can offer any insights.

I started a campaign about a week ago and it is S-L-O-W to ramp up! My bid is $2, my budget is $80/day and so far the campaign has spent only $47 in 7 days.

Google says: 
Your campaign will take a week or two to ramp up to its normal performance.
[that was here: https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Mobile-Apps-and-Calls/FAQ-Universal-App-Campaigns-MobileMonday/td-p/516440
].

But this slow ramp-up seems a little ridiculous to me. On the plus side, the conversion rates and costs-per-conversion I'm seeing so far are excellent (albeit with little data).

Answer (score 0):

Increase your bid and make sure that the daily budget is a minimum of 50x the bid. Example: for a $2 target cpi, you should have a budget that is $100 or above.